# How do I make a canvas containing an image and user control rotatable?

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, pixelsense, scatterview

I am using scatterview to show an Image and a usercontrol. canMove and canScale is set to false from c# code to restrict scaling and moving. I am able to rotate the scatterview by setting canRotate to true. Please anyone guide me if i am doing it right.

```
<s:ScatterView>
  <s:ScatterViewItem Name="sctHanger" >
    <Canvas Name="qrhangars" >
      <Image Name="imginfo" Source="/Resources/info.fw.png" Width="100"           Height="100"  TouchDown="imginfo_TouchDown"  />
      <pie:UserControl1 Name="userctrl1" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="85,70,40,40" />
    </Canvas>
  </s:ScatterViewItem>
</s:ScatterView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a fine way to make something rotatable